# AJAX Username check not validating

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, html

PHP/MySQL.
I have created a simple form containing a username textfield and a button. Page name is **checkusername.php**. I wrote an AJAX function also. Then I have another page **usercheckpage.php** to where value from checkusername.php is passed via the AJAX function `getResult()`.

In *usercheckpage.php*, username is checked in the database table, if it is already present, then `'username not available'` is shown and if available `'username available'` is shown.

BUT THE PROBLEM IS, even if the alert message `'username not available'` is displayed, if I click the submit button, the value is passed into my next page *insertusername.php*. I don't want the form to get submitted if username is not avaiable. I tried html5 validation. But it didn't quite work well.

Here is my code:

**checkusername.php**

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="../controller/insertusername.php">
label for="txtuname"></label>
<input type="text" name="txtuname" id="txtuname" required onblur="getResult(this.value);" />
<span id="showusername"></span>
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="SUBMIT" />
</form>
```

---

AjAX FUnction

```
function getResult(uname)
{  

    if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {  
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();

        }
    else
    {
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()//callback fn
        {   
          if(xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
              {

                   document.getElementById('showusername').innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;

              }

                  xmlhttp.open("GET","checkusername.php?variable="+uname,true);
                  xmlhttp.send();

                  }
```

---

**checkusername.php**

```
<?php
include '../model/Query.php';
$un=$_GET["variable"];
$name="select username from login where username='".$un."'";
$res=getData($name);
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res))
{
    $name1=$row["username"];
} 
if($un==$name1)
{
    echo "name already exist";
}
else
{
    echo "ok";
}
?>
```

Comment: `$un=$_GET["variable"];` should be `$un=$_GET["txtuname"];`

Comment: You need to apply the `getResult` outcome to the forms `submit` event to manipulate the forms submission.

Comment: what about enable or disable the submit button depending on the username availablity?

Comment: I have stored the value of txtuname to a variable named 'variable' in the getResult(). Check the 3rd line from the bottom in the function. So it's correct. I tried echoing the value of $un in checkusername.php, and it gave the username that i entered in the first page.

Comment: I was thinking to implement the same username check that we see in social networking sites. Do you have any other suggestions other than disabling the sumbit button?? @ Ian Brindley

Comment: **Danger**: You are **vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/)** that you need to [defend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) yourself from.

Comment: Why dont u use jquery's ajax methods and make ur life easy??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML

add on submit event

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="../controller/insertusername.php" onsubmit="checkUsername()">
```

AJAX

edit your getResult function in order to return true or false

```
if(xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
    document.getElementById('showusername').innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;

    return (xmlhttp.responseText == 'ok') true : false;
}
```

then create a very simple function that onsubmit checks if the username is available or not. If not, just return false and the form will NOT be submitted.

```
function checkUsername(){
    var username = document.getElementById("txtuname").value;
    if(!getResult(username))
        return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

add on submit event

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="../controller/insertusername.php" onsubmit="checkUsername()">
```

**AJAX**

edit your getResult function in order to return `true` or `false`

```
if(xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
    document.getElementById('showusername').innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;

    return (xmlhttp.responseText == 'ok') true : false;
}
```

then create a very simple function that `onsubmit` checks if the username is available or not. If not, just return `false` and the form will NOT be submitted.

```
function checkUsername(){
    var username = document.getElementById("txtuname").value;
    if(!getResult(username))
        return false;
}
```

hope this helps :-)

Answer (score 0):

to work it well change your button to

```
<input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="check()">
```

and add method

```
function check(){
    if(getElementById('showusername').innerHTML=="ok"){
        document.getElementById("form1").submit();
    }
}
```

I hope it work...